# Get the latest timeStamp from the json response

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I want to get the latest timeStamp and userID from the json response for which the actualDataArray.status =="Approved" ,for populating it on the template

```
{
  "dataArray": [
    {
      "Id": 11,
      "Name": "HJ Enterprises",
      "Code": "HJC",
      "description": "HJ APProved",
      "Status": "OK",
      "actualDataArray": [
        {
          "timeStamp": "2019-05-07-06.26.23.991068",
          "status": "Approved",
          "userID": "@23444",
          "articles": ""
        },
        {
          "timeStamp": "2019-05-07-06.37.27.978668",
          "status": "Rejected",
          "userID": "@1234",
          "articles": "articles"
        },
        {
          "timeStamp": "2019-05-08-06.26.28.991068",
          "status": "Approved",
          "userID": "@1233e",
          "articles": ""
        },
      ],


    },
```

expected output should be the latest timeStamp and userId corresponding to that timestamp.
 Please help me with this.

Comment: Please add your attempt to the question.

Comment: @adiga i am trying with the filter method but not able to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this you can get the latest object with Approved status.

```js
const data = {
  "dataArray": [
    {
      "Id": 11,
      "Name": "HJ Enterprises",
      "Code": "HJC",
      "description": "HJ APProved",
      "Status": "OK",
      "actualDataArray": [
        {
          "timeStamp": "2019-05-07-06.26.23.991068",
          "status": "Approved",
          "userID": "@23444",
          "articles": ""
        },
        {
          "timeStamp": "2019-05-07-06.37.27.978668",
          "status": "Rejected",
          "userID": "@1234",
          "articles": "articles"
        },
        {
          "timeStamp": "2019-05-08-06.26.28.991068",
          "status": "Approved",
          "userID": "@1233e",
          "articles": ""
        },
      ],


    }
  ]
}

let dataArr = data.dataArray
dataArr.forEach((dataPoint, i) => {
  let actualDataArray = dataPoint.actualDataArray
  let sortedActualDataArray = actualDataArray.sort((a, b) => {
    (new Date(a.timeStamp) > new Date(b.timeStamp)) ? 1 : -1
  })
  
  let timeStampElem = undefined
  
  if(dataPoint.status != "Ok"){
    timeStampElem = tempSearchArr[0]
  }
  else {
    timeStampElem = tempSearchArr[1]
  }
  console.log(timeStampElem)
  console.log(`TimeStamp: ${timeStampElem.timeStamp}`)
  console.log(`UserID: ${timeStampElem.userID}`)
})
```

Comment: that worked perfectly fine..could you please add the functionality to the code so that if the status != Ok in that case it should take the second latest timestamp

Comment: Updated @sm770 . Plus I added array support, so that it runs through every element in dataArray.

Comment: aleady the code is running inside a map function..so loop will not be required in that case?

Comment: Where is there a map function? @sm770

Comment: this.dataApprovalList1 = this.dataApprovalList.map(data => {
 let value = data.actualBelowTheLineTradeAuditArray
              .sort((a, b) => (new Date(a.reviseTimestamp) > new Date(b.reviseTimestamp)) ? 1 : -1).find((el) => el.reviseManualTradeStatus != "Traded");
return {
 "reviseTimestamp": value.reviseTimestamp ? value.reviseTimestamp:null,
              "reviseUserId": value.reviseUserId ?value.reviseUserId:null ,
              "reviseManualTradeStatus": data.reviseManualTradeStatus ? value.reviseManualTradeStatus:null,

Comment: if status!=Appoved , show latest timeStamp if staus==Approved show second latest timeStamp

Comment: added in comments

Comment: What exactly is your question now? What do you want? My example is working according to your question and first comment.

Comment: YES it is working..thanks a lot .. just wanted some modification

Comment: @MauriceNino...the thing is if the status in my question is status != Approved, take the latest timeStamp and userid corresponding to that and if the latest status is aprroved then select the one before that in the array

Comment: I dont quite understand what you really mean. Which status? timeStamp and userid corresponding to what exactly? What is before? Like before in the sorted array or the original one?

Comment: @MauriceNino--Nothing to do with actualDataArray.status , if Status(ouside array) NOT= Ok, then take the latest timeStamp/UserID .....else if Status(ouside array)==Ok, then take the second latest timeStamp and UserId?..did you got it bro?

Comment: Got it. Changed the example in the answer.

Comment: I do no see any changes?

Comment: @sm770 basically I flipped the if/else on `dataPoint.status`. It already implements your request.

Comment: I did not get that what is the use of  el.status == "Approved" @MauriceNino

Comment: It filters out all elements with the status beeing `"Approved"`

Comment: I don't need the status of elements inside actualDataArray...only the Status (outisde array) is considered..if that is NOT=Ok take latestTimeSatmp/User ,else take seond timestamp/user...

Comment: Why did you ask for that in your original question then?

Comment: ...It was modified thereafter sorry for that...this is the real scenario now

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```js
var jsonObj = {
    "dataArray": [
        {
            "Id": 11,
            "Name": "HJ Enterprises",
            "Code": "HJC",
            "description": "HJ APProved",
            "Status": "OK",
            "actualDataArray": [
                {
                    "timeStamp": "2019-05-07-06.26.23.991068",
                    "status": "Approved",
                    "userID": "@23444",
                    "articles": ""
                },
                {
                    "timeStamp": "2019-05-07-06.37.27.978668",
                    "status": "Rejected",
                    "userID": "@1234",
                    "articles": "articles"
                },
                {
                    "timeStamp": "2019-05-08-06.26.28.991068",
                    "status": "Approved",
                    "userID": "@1233e",
                    "articles": ""
                },
            ],
        }
    ]
};
var approvedUsers = {};
var totalData = jsonObj.dataArray.length;
var i = 0;
while(i < totalData) {
    var actualsData = jsonObj.dataArray[i].actualDataArray;
    var actualLength = actualsData.length;
    var j = 0;
    while(j < actualLength) {
        if (actualsData[j].status === "Approved") {
            approvedUsers[actualsData[j].userID] = actualsData[j];
        }
        j += 1;
    }    
    i += 1;
}
console.log(approvedUsers);
```

In this, I am aggregating the data with "Approved" status in a separate `var` and at the end showing it in a `console.log()`. You may use this `var` as per your need.